# Регулярное выражение ведет себя странным образом

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Создал свою CMS с возможностью интеграции шаблонов. Например, вписываю `{{shablon2}}`, вместо него вставляется файл `shablon2.php`.

Код элементарен:

```
if(preg_match_all("/{{(.*)}}/",$this->data['content'],$result)){
 // подключение файла и html-код
 }
```

Странно, что на локалке работает, а на хосте - не хочет.
После заливки на хост, регулярка не работает, а на странице появляется фраза `{{shablon2}}`.

Опытным путем удалось выяснить что стоит мне поставить парочку лишних пробелов и код начинает работать!

```
if(preg_match_all("/{{(.*)}}/","  " . $this->data['content'],$result)){
     // подключение файла и html-код
 }
```

Почему так происходит? Что это за тайна такая? Я уже 3 часа просидел над кодом. Ничего не получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала попробуйте экранировать метасимволы `{}`:

```
/\\{\\{(.*)\\}\\}/
```

Comment: привет))) Почему Денвер "хавает" предыдущий код, а хост - не хочет кушать???

Comment: я давно вас знаю - еще на хэшкоде)))

Comment: Спасибо, это был правильный ответ

Comment: не могу понять, для чего два (!) раза экранируются символы о_О

Comment: @Deus это регулярки ... сначала защищаемся от обратного слэша которым экранируем спецсимволы) ....

Comment: просто я не знал,что {} - нужно экранировать.

Comment: @ReinRaus, почему на Денвере мой прежний код работает, но на хосте - никак? Ну почему???

Comment: @Deus честно говоря не могу подсказать. Используйте Open Server, тогда такой код одинаково не будет работать везде.